# Generate tree menu with Dropdown - Cakephp 3.8

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I created a menu of categories using tree in cakephp3. I can add, edit, display and everything. However, I can't generate the dropdown menu because I have doubts to manipulate the submenus items (children).

I'm doing it that way

I managed to get all the nodes with the id equal to 0 (parent menu) like this:

```
$children = $this->Categories->find('children', ['for' => 1])->find('threaded')->toArray();
```

and

```
<?php
foreach ($children as $child) {
echo "{$child->nome} \n"; 
}
?>
```

I am trying to catch the children of these items in another loop. This way I believe that I can manipulate the style and leave the menu the way I want. Any tips to get these child items from the menus being displayed? Thanks for the help!

Thanks for any comment!

Comment: This tutorial may be help you https://youtu.be/WxMh4KsMHYA

Comment: Thanks for the video. There he works with two tableas. Menu and submenu. I work with just one with the fields: id, name, slug, parent_id, lft, rght. Thus, the doubt arises to manipulate the child menu.